# Scala Databinder Dispatch Http shutdown

Tags: scala, future

Why `http.shutdown()` isn't stopping the program?

This is the example:

```
package hello

import dispatch._, Defaults._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main extends App {

    val h = host("maps.googleapis.com")
    val req = h / "maps" / "api" / "distancematrix" / "xml"
    val params = req <<? Map("origins" -> "Berlin",
                             "destinations" -> "Warsaw",
                             "language" -> "pl")
    val http = new Http
    val ratioHttp: Future[xml.Elem] =
        http(params OK as.xml.Elem)

    println(Await.result(ratioHttp, 60.seconds))

    http.shutdown()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's hanging there and not `Await.result`? This works just fine for me.

Comment: It awaits result, prints it, shutdown http and hangs there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with Dispatch version. 0.11.1 works fine.

Comment: I use 0.11.2 and it hangs, too